# How to create user control in Spring MVC Framework

Tags: spring-mvc, user-controls

Is there any standard way to create user control in spring MVC ? say Autocomplete Textbox.
I have created it in ASP.net

I am looking for your reply.
Regards
Rohit More

Comment: Spring MVC is not a UI platform, but a structural framework. So the answer would be no. You need to choose a UI technology that suits your needs, integrate it with Spring and create your user controls there.

Comment: Mr. Kelmer sir would you mind may I ask for any tutorial or kinda of Exmaple? I am new comer in Java.

Comment: That depends on the platform you choose. Here's a tutorial for PrimeFaces: http://www.javabeat.net/primefaces-spring-hibernate-integration-example/ Here's another tutorial with ZK http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Integration/Middleware_Layer/Spring